# How does an IoT Edge Module route a message to a registered device while still being on the Edge?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

For simplicity, let's consider Microsft's tutorial for creating a module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-visual-studio-develop-module?view=iotedge-2018-06

Through this tutorial, we learn to listen to messages routed to the edge hub via the SimulatedTemperatureSensor.

I have taken this a little further where I registered an additional device, `myAwesomeDevice` (which is a console app that creates messages similar to SimulatedTemperatureSensor). `myAwesomeDevice` now ships x messages to the edge hub. I have added an additional route to the aforementioned tutorial that listens for messages from `myAwesomeDevice` and sends them into a BrokeredEndpoint.

What I want to accomplish now, if it is possible, is to have `myAwesomeDevice` be able to receive messages from the module created in the tutorial. Let's imagine `myAwesomeDevice` is now software that displays to the user running the software all the temperature metrics. Is it possible for this module to send that message to `myAwesomeDevice`?

I have begun to head down the `SetMethodHandlerAsync` as a direct message approach, but am struggling to grasp if 1) this is correct 2) how the device receives the message

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this with the `InvokeMethodAsync` method on ModuleClient.

Comment: Can you verify as the answer?